# Possible numbers on a broken screen

Tags: code-golf

A screen consisted of some LED segments like such:

```
 _ _    _ _ _
|_|_|..._|_|_|
|_|_|   _|_|_|
```

However, some of the LEDs are broken, and it's possible that only these are left:

```
 _ _
 _|_|
|_|_|
```

Now, you're required to output all integers possibly expressed on this screen. An integer, something matching RegEx `/^0$|^-?[1-9][0-9]*$/`, can be expressed iff each of its character can be displayed in order using the unbroken LEDs, any two characters not overlapping or touching.

Shapes of characters `0123456789-` are given below:

```
 _     _  _       _   _  _   _   _
| |,|, _|,_|,|_|,|_ ,|_ , |,|_|,|_|,_
|_| | |_  _|   |  _| |_|  | |_|  _|
```

Sample Input:

```
 _ _
 _|_|
|_|_|
```

Sample Output:

```
{-7,-1,0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,11,21,31,71}
```

Your can take input in reasonable ways e.g. taking a repeating pattern of a good screen and treat \$
\begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
\$ as \$[
\begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
\begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix},
\begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
\color{cyan}{\begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}}]
\$ (cyan means broken); or maybe 5 arrays of each kinds of LEDs, etc. Your output needn't be sorted, either. Shortest code wins.

### Notes:

- A good screen actually can be \$
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \$, but we'll just input it as \$
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \color{cyan}{\begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}-\\-\\-\\\end{matrix}
  \begin{matrix}|\\|\\\end{matrix}
  \$.
- I thought this question and the other LED one together in one question but later decided to separate.

Comment: This would be much more readable if the digits were in code blocks rather than MathJax

Comment: @Arnauld `An integer, something matching RegEx /^0$|^-?[1-9][0-9]*$/`

Comment: @xash Changed uncolored screens into code blocks, but colored ones remain

Comment: @pxeger Changed uncolored screens into code blocks, but colored ones remain

Comment: Can the LED display output leave extra space between digits to avoid broken LED's?

Comment: @xnor Yes as it's displayed in order

Comment: Please consider add some more testcases.

Answer (score 10):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 164 bytes

Expects an array of 5-bit integers, matching the segments as described below:

[image: segments]

Returns a set.

The code contains 3 unprintable characters, which are escaped below.

```javascript
f=([v,...a],p,o=(s=new Set,''),P)=>1/v?f(a,v,o,Buffer("w`>|i]_d\x7f}\x03\x08").map((x,i)=>(p|v%4<<5)&x^x||P>3&&x%6&&P-8|x%10||f(a,v,o+('1-'[i-10]||i),x))):o&&1/o?s.add(+o):s
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVBRb9MwEH7gBfVXnCo1PlPHaxggNOpMQoLnSn2plIXgJc7wVOJgZ5krPPHTi9MNNp1k3efvu/vu7laO0tVW90PamUYdj63AYmScc1mynhmBTnTqHrZqYIRQtqEiz87GyxYlG5lhn@/aVlmc33/Pgy6r5s/Dq9dzyn/KHtEzHdXYh3Hxbr1@TxP/zYewyc@TxC8@JMkm/Rj8IluF8NRtiSRLSaHTbFWGoCnzlNILkyTZmbl0XDYNLg29cEerft1pq5C0jlBulWy@6r3aHroaV5QPZjtY3d0g5a7f6wHnV91VF6dqjf0i6x/oQOTwewYgQUBRfoqZe5a@EKJjcKCTuogXceUzUTPwJ0IWHvIcshKCAKxBCCAVgRDgMQ@EwnoNHhbwFt7AOSzhAClklE62VsVZIK5/QrXpnNkrvjc3OBlGtuTO2AHjfeD60S8WX1N@a3SHhAGZ@jzQI1QxZrsqVGEWTu9s@niCL8HuBP7Jd/8LqvAX)

(Includes some post-processing to sort the results for the sake of clarity.)

#### How?

The full byte describing enabled segments is obtained by shifting the two least significant bits of the current mask `v` by 5 positions to the left and adding them to the previous mask `p`:

```javascript
p | v % 4 << 5
```

The shapes of the digits and the minus sign are encoded as the ASCII codes of a 12-character string. Note that there are two versions of the "1" (right-aligned and left-aligned).

```
 119 |   96  | 62 | 124 | 105 | 93 | 95 | 100 | 127 | 125 |   3   | 8
-----+-------+----+-----+-----+----+----+-----+-----+-----+-------+---
   0 | 1 (a) |  2 |   3 |   4 |  5 |  6 |   7 |   8 |   9 | 1 (b) | -

(a): right-aligned
(b): left-aligned
```

The test `P > 3 && x % 6 && P - 8 | x % 10` is used to reject characters that are touching each other:

```javascript
P > 3 &&  // 1) the previous character is not empty
          //    and is not a left-aligned "1"
x % 6 &&  // 2) the current character is not a right-aligned "1"
          //    (the only character whose encoding byte is 0 modulo 6)
P - 8 |   // 3) the previous character is not a minus sign
x % 10    //    or the current character is not a "7"
          //    (the only character whose encoding byte is 0 modulo 10)
```

Answer (score 2):

## [Jelly](https://github.com/DennisMitchell/jelly), 92 bytes

```
Ø0ṭ;ḣ2$}¥Ɲ“⁸ɠḊṭṆƙ²ġ°ɦẋ‘BḊ€¤oẠ¥€T¥ⱮịØD;”-¤©;€⁶Œp®ḟ”1pƊḟ““-7”¤i$ƝẸ$Ðḟḟ€⁶Ḣ;ḟɗ€”-ḟ““-”ḟ”0;ɗṪ$€VQ
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0rNyan8///wDIOHO9daP9yx2Eil9tDSY3MfNcx51Ljj5IKHO7qAEg93th2beWjTkYWHNpxc9nBX96OGGU5AmUdNaw4tyX@4a8GhpUBmCJDcuO7h7u7DM1ysHzXM1T205NBKa6DEo8ZtRycVHFr3cMd8oLBhwbEuMGsOEOmaA0UOLclUOTb34a4dKocnAGVAkmBND3csArpo/snpIC7QPIQuIA9imIH1yekPd65SAaoIC/x/uP3hzkX//0cb6BhCYKxOtCEa2wAEYwE)

Horribly long for a Jelly answer but I think it works! A monadic link taking a list of lists of five 0s and 1s and returning a list of integers. The footer sorts the output. 1 represents a working LED segment and 0 a non-working one. They are numbered left to right and top to bottom, so the first two integers represent the left-hand side of the display and the next three represent the three horizontal segments.

Answer (score 1):

## [Charcoal](https://github.com/somebody1234/Charcoal), <s>158</s> 138 bytes

```
⊞υ⟦θηζω⟧ＦυＦ¹¹«≔⪪§⪪”{⊟∨÷θＡ<∧mTMm⁰)¶Þ[u↘∕{‽ＵïÞ6Zξ-Φ⊟F∕↖;⁶Ｃ↑Ｈ;z⦃”⸿κ¶ε≔ΦＬζ⬤ε⬤ν№⁺ §§ιξ⁺μρπδ¿δ⊞υＥι⎇⁼³μ⁺λ§Ｉ⊖κ⁰⭆λ⎇›ξ⁺⌊δＬ§εμν »ΦＥυ⊟ι∧››ι-№Φιμ-⁼ιＩＩι
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TVFNb4MwDD2PX2FxSqRUWrVjT6j70KRVQupu64RQSSFqCG0IW9ex387sQNoi4hc79nOes61yu21yPQxp11asE/BxFFAJOAv4/uSLaNdYYB0Hj/M5h9/oLmlbVRq2PmjlWOJeTSFPkxfDxmS4YGOBsIceTdaji0j/GIfMx@HWBZ8GMBYYgJDch5Qb13P6eO9XOLq0u7hYGAuINzbmAvactoa2EtUFKc9KO2nZmzSlq9gZTxOtmRzBCFg2nXEs1V2LCpEtiA6oBJywyCfUAizn6B24h4L6qB2wgkMY8io/UM27tCa3P@zp2OW6ZQ8C6sCir02WeevYo9xaWUvjZMH2RHtPZu2sMiWx6Svbi5U5qTlNVCtlVN3V2F/ApDBQS@rob4kiURnt8bp/UYq8LoyF@PHSaYOXptzEFJcmAVFNPKOxjqOaKtWoiE4QJpkY9JK8UXz8FsOAT5ZF@FpZH/Vkh9mX/gc) Link is to verbose version of code. Too long because I'm doing string manipulation instead of bit twiddling. Explanation:

```
⊞υ⟦θηζω⟧
```

Start a breadth first search with a trial of the input and no characters so far.

```
ＦυＦ¹¹«
```

Loop over each trial and character (`-` plus `0`..`9`).

```
≔⪪§⪪”{⊟∨÷θＡ<∧mTMm⁰)¶Þ[u↘∕{‽ＵïÞ6Zξ-Φ⊟F∕↖;⁶Ｃ↑Ｈ;z⦃”⸿κ¶ε
```

Extract the display for the given character.

```
≔ΦＬζ⬤ε⬤ν№⁺ §§ιξ⁺μρπδ
```

Find whether we can place the character using the remaining segments.

```
¿δ⊞υＥι⎇⁼³μ⁺λ§Ｉ⊖κ⁰⭆λ⎇›ξ⁺⌊δＬ§εμν
```

If so then add a new trial with the adjacent segments removed.

```
»ΦＥυ⊟ι∧››ι-№Φιμ-⁼ιＩＩι
```

Only output those trials that are integers (e.g. exclude `0-0`).